Why $\mathbb{Q}( \zeta) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_1) \cdots \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_r)$ with additional property ? ( Expression of cyclotomic field as compositums )
Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity with $n=l_1^{\nu_1} \cdots l_r^{\nu_r}$ the factorization through prime numbers. Then $\zeta_i = \zeta^{n/l_i^{\nu_i}}$ is a primitive $l_i^{\nu_i}$-th root of unity.
Then, $\mathbb{Q}( \zeta) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_1) \cdots \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_r)$ with $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_1) \cdots \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{i-1}) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_i) = \mathbb{Q}$ for all $i$? If so, why ?  Can we find associated proof ? This statement occurs in the Neukirch's Algebraic number theory, proof of p.60, $ (10.2)$ Proposition : $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is given by $1 ,\zeta, \dots, , \zeta^{d-1}$, with $d=\varphi(n)$.

In your notation, $\mathbf Q(\zeta_1)\cdots \mathbf Q(\zeta_{i-1}) = \mathbf Q(\zeta')$ where $\zeta'$ is a root of unity with order $l_1^{\nu_1}\cdots l_{i-1}^{\nu_{i-1}}$.  So you are asking why  $\mathbf Q(\zeta')\cap \mathbf Q(\zeta_{i}) = \mathbf Q$.  The roots of unity $\zeta'$ and $\zeta_i$ have relatively prime orders.  Use ramification over $l_i$ to show that intersection is $\mathbf Q$.
More generally, you should try to show that $\mathbf Q(\zeta')\cap \mathbf Q(\zeta'') = \mathbf Q$ when $\zeta'$ and $\zeta''$ are roots of unity with relatively prime orders.

O.K. Why $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_1 ) \cdots \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{i-1}) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta ' )$?

That question is much more basic than algebraic number theory. Maybe a more general version will be clearer to you: if $\zeta$ and $\widetilde \zeta$ have relatively prime orders, then show $\mathbf Q(\zeta)\mathbf Q(\widetilde \zeta) = \mathbf Q(\zeta\widetilde\zeta)$.  If you don't see why this is true, then work out the special case when $\zeta$ has order $3$ and $\widetilde \zeta$ has order $5$.
